# Какое событие при скроле к другому блоку добавит класс?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Когда край окна достигнет блока с классом **.our-mission**, то к блоку с классом **.nav-left** должен добавиться класс **.fixed-nav-left**, а если скролить к началу, то как только верх окна браузера покинет блок с классом **.our-mission** то удалится класс **.fixed-nav-left**

```
<header>
   header страницы
</header>

<section class="our-mission">
   <nav class="nav-left">
      Меню сайта
   </nav>
  Our mission
</section>
```

Comment: событие само по себе никогда ничего не добавит, нужный вам функционал реализует Intersection API

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Jquery: как заставить функцию scroll вызываться только один раз?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657444/jquery-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-scroll-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш скрипт:

```
var stickySidebar = $(".our-mission").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickySidebar) {
        $('.nav-left').addClass('fixed-nav-left');
    }
    else {
        $('.nav-left').removeClass('fixed-nav-left');
    }
});
```